# Transmitting analog TV using a computer

Tags: video

I wonder what's needed to transmit analog TV using a computer.

The requirements would be:

- Using a computer as source.
- Ability to share the full screen.
- Any PAL or NTSC Tuner.

Multi-channel transmission would also be nice, maybe using multiple desktops for different channels and multiple virtual audio cards for each channels audio.

Preferably a PCI-E Card one could just connect to an antenna cable but an SDI Graphics Card with some external "converter" would also be an acceptable solution.

---

*I've found very little information on this on the web but while working at a computer store I once got my hands on a PCI card I think did just this for hotels*

Comment: Does it need to be analog? Are you thinking of NTSC or one of the other analog standards out there? Does it need to be on a frequency received by a regular off-the-shelf TV tuner? Do you have any licenses needed by your jurisdiction for TV transmission on those frequencies?

Comment: Of the shelf TV tuner required. PAL or NTSC. No license required if using cables.

Comment: Ah, when you said "transmit" I thought you meant wirelessly. So you're just looking for something like an RF modulator like old VCRs and 1980's computers used to have, but that you could hook up to a modern computer (perhaps via VGA or DisplayPort or the like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is an RF Modulator that works on typical computer video outputs (such as VGA, HDMI, or DisplayPort). I did a little looking and found [some on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=hdmi%20rf%20modulator), so I know that it's possible, though I don't have any experience with any of them to actually recommend one over another. I don't know if it might be easier to find a [HDMI-to-RCA adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06W9LQDBB) that you then connect to a more "normal" (or at least easier to find) [RCA RF Modulator](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0014KKV7W). (All those links are just for examples; there are plenty of products from plenty of brands and plenty of retailers out there.)

Note that in order to share "the full screen", you'll need to use a pretty low resolution on the computer, just because NTSC and PAL don't have that many lines of video available compared to what people are used to nowadays.

Comment: Excellent answer. Yes, DVB might be a better option if the receivers support it.